paste pdf image with correct width and height and position to svg file in python using fitz
`i am trying to convert  pdf file to svg with correct formating
i am using the fitz pymupdf library
the text is formatted correctly but i cant adjust the image
"this is my first time working with pdf or svg"
this is the code
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import base64
import zipfile
def pdf_to_svg_with_text_and_images(pdf_path, output_zip_path):
    document = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    num_pages = len(document)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(output_zip_path, 'w') as zipf:
        for page_index in range(num_pages):
            page = document.load_page(page_index)
        
            svg_header = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
            version="1.1" id="main1" width="{width}" height="{height}">
            <g>
            '''.format(width=int(page.rect.width), height=int(page.rect.height))
        
            svg_content = ""
            current_y = 0  # Starting Y position for text
            text_instances = page.get_text("dict")["blocks"]
            for instance in text_instances:
                if "lines" in instance:
                    for line in instance["lines"]:
                        for span in line["spans"]:
                            svg_content += f'<text style="fill:#000000;font-family: 
                            {span["font"]};font-size:{span["size"]}px;" fill-opacity="1" x="
                            {span["bbox"][0]}" y="{span["bbox"][3]}">{span["text"]}</text>\n'
                        current_y = max(current_y, span["bbox"][3])  
        
        
            image_list = page.get_images(full=True)

            if image_list:
                for img_index, img in enumerate(image_list):
                    xref = img[0]  
                    base_image = document.extract_image(xref)
                    image_bytes = base_image["image"]
                    img_width, img_height = 400, 400  
                    img_x, img_y = img[1], img[2]  

                
                    img_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode("utf-8")
                
                
                    svg_content += f'<image x="{img_x}" y="{img_y}" width="{img_width}"
                    height="
                    {img_height}" xlink:href="data:image/{base_image["ext"]};base64,
                    {img_base64}"/>\n'
        
            svg_footer = '''
            </g>
            </svg>'''

        
            if svg_content:
                svg_filename = f'page{page_index + 1}.svg'
                full_svg_content = svg_header + svg_content + svg_footer
                zipf.writestr(svg_filename, full_svg_content)
                print(f"SVG file {svg_filename} added to zip")

    document.close()


input_pdf_path = 'testing_new.pdf'
output_zip_path = 'output_svgs.zip'


pdf_to_svg_with_text_and_images(input_pdf_path, output_zip_path)`

`

I have put the pdf file and output in the link plz check it
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oCthojmcJhNZMtNiSC36oKLGzxqBWC9I?usp=sharing

if you check the svg file code
the image is embbed in the page
but doesnot showup

this way the svg file are more like a image of pdf page
like you can't edit it
i was trying that it can be edited even after conversion form pdf to svg
